# $a$ sum of $2$ squares and $b$ sum of $3$ squares imply $a^2b$ is sum of $3$ squares.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials

I have been given the following problem to solve and am having a hard time finding a solution. I feel that one way, perhaps the only way, is to use a polynomial identity but I can't determine it.

Let $a,b$ two positive integers. If $a$ is sum of $2$ squares and $b$ is sum of $3$ squares then $a^2b$ is sum of three squares.

NOTE.-The sums are mean "primitive" (i.e. with coprime solutions).

Comment: Your "primitive" edit may change the question: if $a=1^2+1^2$ and $b=1^2+1^2+1^2$ then we would be looking at $a^2b=12$ which is $2^2+2^2+2^2$ but not the sum of three coprime squares, so it would not be possible to prove the claim with your extra condition

Comment: @Henry: The answer to this problem has been given below in second comment. Regards  and respect for you.

Comment: Wikipedia suggests emphasizing that, for positive binary forms, the class number is the count of Gauss reduced forms, $ax^2 + b xy + c y^2$  gives triple $(a,b,c).$  For discriminant $-4n,$  the rules are: $\gcd(a,b,c)=1\; ; \; \; $$b^2 - 4ac = -4n \; ; \; \;$  $|b| \leq a \leq c\; ; \; \; $ if $a=c$  then $b \geq 0\; ; \; \; $  if $  |b| = a$  then $b = a\; ; \; \; $

Comment: second try:  your  positive number $a^2b,$   as long as it is not divisible by $4,$  can always be expressed $a^2 b = x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ with $\gcd(x,z,y) = 1.$

Answer (score 1):

You do not need any property for $a$, since its square is a square.

If $b=v^2+w^2+z^2$ (copying Simon Fox's description) then

$$a^2b =a^2v^2+a^2w^2+a^2z^2 = (av)^2+(aw)^2+(az)^2$$

Comment: The langage commonly used in these questions means sum of three squares coprimes. Likely Phytagorean triples for which $(3,4,5)$ is the same solution as $(3n,4n,5n)$ (projectively equivalent).

Comment: @Piquito if $a=1^2+1^2$ and $b=1^2+1^2+1^2$ then we would be looking at $a^2b=12$ which is $2^2+2^2+2^2$ but not the sum of three coprime squares, so it would not be possible to prove the claim with your coprime extra condition

Comment: The answer when $a=a_1^2+a_2^2$ and $b=b_1^2+b_2^2+b_3^2$ is $$a^2b=(ab_1-2(a_1b_1+a_2b_2)a_1)^2+(ab_2-2(a_1b_1+a_2b_2)a_2)^2+(ab_3)^2$$

Comment: @Piquito When $a=1^2+1^2$ and $b=1^2+1^2+1^2$ that again gives $12=4+4+4$ which does not look coprime to me

Comment: @Henry.- Don't be stubborn, please. What interest here are sums of "primitive" solutions. Solutions of $x=3y^2$ are trivial ones here.

Answer (score 0):

Any positive integer $n$ that is not divisible by 4, also $n \neq 7 \pmod 8,$ can be written primitively as the sum of three squares.  The number of such primitive representations is a certain multiple of $h(-4n).$  This number is the count of primitive binary quadratic forms of discriminant $-4n.$  We always have $h(-4n) \geq 1$   because there is always the form $x^2 + n y^2.$

Oh, permutations of a triple are considered separate, also negating one or more variables...a triple (x,y,z)  with $ x > y > z > 0$  therefore counts as $48$ representations. Anyway,

For $n > 1$ and $ n \equiv 1 \pmod 8,$  $\; \; R_{0}(n) = 12 h(-4n).$

For $ n \equiv 3 \pmod 8,$  $ \; \; R_{0}(n) = 8 h(-4n).$

For $ n \equiv 5 \pmod 8,$  $ \; \; R_{0}(n) = 12 h(-4n).$

For $ n \equiv 2 \pmod 8,$  $ \; \; R_{0}(n) = 12 h(-4n).$

For $ n \equiv 6 \pmod 8,$  $ \; \;R_{0}(n) = 12 h(-4n).$